# Memory Issue in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, memory-management, cocos2d-x

Thanx in advance..I have a problem , how we release memory in cocos2dx ??
In my game, my first scene takes a lot of memory because there are so many animations run at a single time on this scene,there are so many animations , so i am satisfied with this but when we go to next scene, it does not release previous memory used,this is my problem so how we release memory used by previous scene when we change the scene?

Answer (score 0):

To go between scenes you can either call `pushScene` or `replaceScene`.

**Push Scene**

If you're pushing between scenes then I recommend that you have a loading scene in between. It should be lightweight so that you have a chance to release everything from your old scene. This is where the `onEnter(DidFinish)` and `onExit(DidStart)` methods come in handy.

The chain of calls would be:

1. `oldScene->onExitDidStart()`
2. `loadScene->onEnter()`
3. `oldScene->onExit()` <-- this is where you release everything
4. `loadScene->onEnterDidFinish()` <-- this is where you load up the new scene
5. `newScene->onEnter()`

and so on... If you've managed your memory correctly then you shouldn't have 2 heavy scenes at once.

**Replace Scene**

This is a much easier scenario. You simply need to make sure that for the new scene you load as little as possible until the old scene has completely disappeared. I.e. when `onEnterDidFinish()` is called, or even 1 frame after it.

Answer (score 0):

**Cocos2d-x supports auto release memory**. For example, when you create a sprite by calling Sprite::create() it will add this sprite to the auto-release pool. If you don't add this sprite to become the child (or n-th leveled child) of the current scene, it will be released.

Do not create an object using **new**,use create() instead when you call the next scene, everything from the last scene are released.